# CSS - How to add dot between navigation title

Tags: css

After I login www.linkedIn.com, the navigation bar on top right displays the title as follows:

```
Welcome, XXX * Skip to Content * Search  * Add Connections * Settings * Help  * Sign Out
```

I would like to know how they add * between different titles. I have used firebug but I didn't see where they add such a small * between titles.

Thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is what they use on LinkedIn:

```
#nav-utility li:before{content:'\00B7';padding-right:5px;}
```

That is, they are using CSS to add an extra character before each list item. `'\00B7'` is a middle dot in Unicode. [`:before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after) is a pseudo-element in CSS; it allows you to act as if there were an element before the content of an element (in this case, before the content of the `<li>` element), and you can use the `content` property to insert some content into that pseudo element. In order to space it properly, they add some padding.

If you look at a slightly larger excerpt, it appears they use a hack (prefixing a property with `*`, which will cause other browsers to ignore the property but older versions of IE to use that property as if the `*` weren't there) that will insert a background image, so older browsers that don't support the `:before` pseudo-element will still get the bullet.

```
#nav-utility li{font-size:110%;color:#666;*background:url(http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/bg/bg_grey_dotted_h-line_3x1.png) no-repeat 0 7px;padding-right:2px;*padding-right:6px;*padding-left:6px;*zoom:1;}
#nav-utility li:last-child{padding-right:0;}
#nav-utility li:before{content:'\00B7';padding-right:5px;}
```

Comment: The reason why you can't see the 'dot' is because content inserted with `content` do not appear in the DOM.

Comment: @Yi Jiang Yes, that's right. I meant to explain that in my post, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Hello Brian,

thank you for this excellent description. I am really impressed!

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can use the :after pseudo-selector:

HTML:

```
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<span>Item 3</span>
<span class="last">Item 4</span>
```

CSS:

```
span:after {
    content: '*';
}
span.last:after {
    content: '';
}
```

​
You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4EAwR/

Comment: This one is nice and simple. To even simplify it, you can remove the `class="last"` and change the last css to `span:last-of-type:after` instead of `span.last:after`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
span:after {
content: '*';
}
span.last:after {
content: '';
}
```

do

```
span:after {
content: '*';
}
span:last-child:after {
content: '';
}
```

This way you don't have to give the last one a special class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevent CSS: `#nav-utility li:before{content:'\00B7';padding-right:5px;}`

The `content:'\00B7';` refers to the ISO code for a little dot character. That character is then placed just before each li within #nav-utility.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the shortest way without extra classes:

```
span:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  content: '\00B7';
}
```