# css - why the content inserted by :before put the navigation item below the normal position

Tags: css

The navigation bar looks like this

```
      HOME LOGIN ABOUT
```

Based on suggestion on this topic: [CSS - How to add dot between navigation title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570480/css-how-to-add-dot-between-navigation-title)

I add the following css rule to append a * to the front of each item.

```
.twoColFixRt #nav-primary .nav li.libar:before {
    content:'*';
}

  <div id="nav-primary">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
     <li class="tab" id="nav-home">
      <a href="#"><span>HOME</span></a>
     </li>           
     ...
     </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Now the navigation bar looks like this

```
   HOME   *   ABOUT
        LOGIN
```

As you can see, the inserted * pushes the item below.

How to fix this issue?

Here is the complete html file for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Edit My Profile | LinkedIn</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style TYPE="text/css">

    #header {
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }

    #header, #body, #footer {
        clear:both;
        margin:0 auto;
        max-width:95%;
        min-width:980px;
        width:98em;
    }

    body {
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
    }

    body {
        border:0 none;
        color:#000000;
        font:62.5%/1.2 Arial,Helvetica,"Nimbus Sans L",sans-serif;
        margin:0;
        outline:0 none;
        padding:0;
    }

        html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
            border:0 none;
            font-family:inherit;
            font-size:100%;
            font-style:inherit;
            font-weight:inherit;
            margin:0;
            outline:0 none;
            padding:0;
            vertical-align:baseline;
        }

        #nav-utility {
            margin:5px 8px;
            position:relative;
            text-align:right;
        }       

        #nav-utility p {
            color:#666666;
            font-size:110%;
            padding-right:2px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #nav-utility a {
            color: #666666;
        }

        #nav-utility ul, #nav-utility li, #nav-utility p {
            display:inline;
        }
        #header {
            width: 970px;
            margin-left: auto ;
            margin-right: auto ;
        }
        #header ul, #header li, #header p, #header fieldset {
            border:medium none;
            list-style-type:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }


        #nav-utility li {
            color:#666666;
            font-size:110%;
            padding-right:2px;
        }

        ol, ul {
            list-style:none outside none;
        }

        #nav-utility ul, #nav-utility li, #nav-utility p {
            display:inline;
        }

        #header ul, #header li, #header p, #header fieldset {
            border:medium none;
            list-style-type:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        #nav-add-connections a {
            color:#006600;
        }

        strong {
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        #nav-utility li:last-child {
            padding-right:0;
        }
        #nav-primary {
background:url("http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/sprite/sprite_global_v3.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -470px transparent;
}
        #nav-primary .wrapper {
             background:url("http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/sprite/sprite_global_v3.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -510px transparent;
        height:39px;
        padding:0 5px;
        }       

        #logo-linkedin {
            float:left;
            margin:8px 10px 0 4px;
            position:relative;
        }       

        #logo-linkedin h1 a {
            background:url("http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/sprite/sprite_global_v3.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
            display:block;
            height:23px;
            text-indent:-12345px;
            width:88px;
        }       

        a {
            color:#006699;
            outline:medium none;
            text-decoration:none;
        }       
        a:hover {
            text-deoration: underline
        }       

#nav-primary ul, #nav-primary li, #nav-primary p, #nav-primary fieldset {
border:medium none;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}       

#nav-primary .nav li.tab {
float:left;
font-size:130%;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:36px;
margin:1px 0 0;
}

#nav-primary .nav a, #nav-primary .nav a:visited, #header #nav-primary .nav li li a, #header #nav-primary .nav li li a:visited {
color:#006699;
text-decoration:none;
}

#nav-primary .nav a span {
display:block;
padding:0 10px;
font-size: 15px;
}

#nav-primary .nav li.libar:before {
    content:'*';
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="member" id="header">
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="nav-primary">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="tab libar" id="nav-primary-home">
                    <a href="/home?trk=hb_tab_home"><span>Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="tab libar" id="nav-primary-profile">
                     <a href="/myprofile?trk=hb_tab_pro"><span>Profile</span></a>
             </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you supporting IE users?  If so you may want to stop for a bit and test in the IE versions you support, then decide if you want to use `:before` :)

Comment: You have: `.twoColFixRt #nav-primary .nav li.libar:before`, where you are searching for *li.libar*; however, the only <li> tag in your example code has `class="tag"` with no *libar* (so, did you mean `#nav-primary .nav li.tab:before`?)

Comment: If you check out this simple example using :before, it's not pushing down your menu items:  http://jsfiddle.net/ExT2F/  I'm going to go with jake33 and ask what the `.libar` class name is doing in there?

Comment: Hello all,

Thank you for all the comments, please take a look at my update post which includes the complete source code that I am working on.

Thank you again

Comment: First, don't put your code before and between the CSS reset codes. To work properly your code needs to be able to override the reset. If you're taking the code from LinkedIn make sure you've copied everything, at least. Also, don't use their images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited version posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/bDpUM/1/

---

Next time, try to take note of how they did it and **write your own code** to replicate it, instead of randomly splicing in other website's codes into your own and end up with the sort of monstrosity you have posted up there.

Comment: Hello Yi,

I have two questions as follows: 1> you don't use list-style-type:none and why the result shown on jsFiddle doesn't display the regular list dot? 2> Can you explain a little what margin-right: -20px means here? It makes the layout looks good, but I don't know why 3> How can I force the * align vertically relative to the navigation bar? I tried vertical-align:baseline, but it doesn't work.

thank you

Comment: @q0987: No.1 is because jsfiddle applies its own reset stylesheet. Not sure which one exactly, but its pretty clean. As for the second question, the -20px margin is there to offset the 20px padding the anchor has, so that the content created would not appear right next to the link, but rather somewhere in between the two links. Try not using `:after` and `content` for anything too complex, as its hard to debug, not very well supported (ahem, IE) and can behave unpredictably.